# iframe redirect with URL masking not working

Tags: redirect, iframe, url-masking

I am trying to redirect my subdomain via my html page which is index.html and I do not want users to see where I am redirecting them So I thought I can use iframe redirect with URL Masking

But It's not working properly. Can you guys fix this.. here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebMail</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Mail">
    <meta name="keywords" content="mail">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23441223-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
  </head>


<frameset rows="100%">
  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
  </frameset>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Please tell me if there any other easy steps like using .htaccess etc..

Answer (score 2):

```
<body style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
<iframe width=100% height=100% src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Try that, good luck